# What file extensions does ffmpeg support?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, file-extension

I'm trying to extract a subtitle from a Blu-ray disc and it is an `hdmv_pgs_subtitle`. So I try

```
ffmpeg -i file.m2ts -map 0:3 -scodec copy rip3/test.sub
```

and get

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): 
Operation not permitted
```

Then I do

```
ffmpeg -i file.m2ts -map 0:3 -scodec copy rip3/test.sup 
ffmpeg -i file.m2ts -map 0:3 -scodec copy rip3/test.srt
```

and a bunch of other different extensions, until I give `.mkv` a shot, which works.

How can I find what extensions ffmpeg allows? I haven't found one place that e.g. names `.mkv` as an extension

`ffmpeg -formats` mentions `matroska`, but doesn't say that `.mkv` is the extension. So is there a way to find all supported file extensions for ffmpeg?

EDIT: After reading the answer from slhck I found the extensions by doing this command in the sourcefolder.

> find . -type f -iname "*.c" -exec egrep -H ".extensions" {} \;

The filename will give some information about what kind of format it is.

Comment: To my knowledge HDMV PGS subtitles cannot be "exported" to a standalone format. What do you need to do with the subtitles, specifically?

Comment: i've never been much good with ffmpeg but fwiw(prob not much!!)besides -formats there's also ffmpeg -codecs

Comment: @slhck it was for ripping a bluray I had. I wanted to dump audio and subtitles and encode the movie. This was really hard because I wanted to do it incrementally (first movie, audio and subtitles) and I couldn't manage to dump the subtitles because I couldn't find the proper extension. Read a couple of places that it was sup, and know of others that are sub, srt, mpsub and some others I saw doing ffmpeg -codecs and -formats. 

@ barlop fwiw codecs is what ffmpeg can read from and encode to not necessarily what it can output to. Format in the case of ffmpeg I think is the container of encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you can see all formats (containers) by calling `ffmpeg -formats`. That they don't mention extensions is probably for the reason that an extension on its own is often meaningless, and you can override the output format by using the `-f` option.

You can see what the common extensions are for a particular (de)muxer. For example:

```
$ ffmpeg -v 1 -h demuxer=matroska
  Demuxer matroska,webm [Matroska / WebM]:
  Common extensions: mkv,mk3d,mka,mks
```

Output formats and their extensions are registered in the encoders. So, you'd find this for Matroska, when looking at the ffmpeg source code:

```
AVOutputFormat ff_matroska_muxer = {
    .name              = "matroska",
    .long_name         = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("Matroska"),
    .mime_type         = "video/x-matroska",
    .extensions        = "mkv",
    ....
```

Input formats are usually not parsed by their extension but the actual contained data.

Also see:

- [FFmpeg Formats Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html)
- [FFmpeg Documentation: Supported File Formats, Codecs, or Features](https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Supported-File-Formats_002c-Codecs-or-Features).

---

The problem is that only two of all the formats ffmpeg can handle support HDMV PGS subtitles:

- MPEG-TS
- MKV (Matroska)

You cannot use an SRT container because it's a different concept. SRT subtitles are based on text, while HDMV PGS subtitles are actual bitmaps.

So, this should work if all you need to do is store the subtitles somewhere:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:s:0 copy -map 0:s:0 output.mks
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you happen to know how I can find out what "things" you can put into what format? Is there a convenient list saying this format supports these "things"?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not really that easy. One could, in theory, parse FFmpeg code in order to find out. Wikipedia has a [fairly comprehensive list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) for common containers though.

Comment: Why not? The wiki looks good, but it seems outdated. Pgssub f.ex. isn't there it seems.